# Long int vs a string in C++?

Tags: c++, string, char, long-integer

Upon my research, I stumbled upon the fact that there is no maximum limit
for a `string`. We can input as many chars or integers as we want. 
If that is the case then why do we have `long int`? 
We could simply use a `string` and convert it to an `int` or a `long int` using `stoi` function, shouldn't that be the case?

Comment: You'd use [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string), wich is not a primitive type but is exactly what you need.

Comment: Do you mean a long string of characters or a string of long characters?

Comment: You need to define what you mean by a "long string", since that is not a common term in programming

Comment: Please do not add the C tag when asking about C++, unless there is some question about interaction or differences between the two languages. The long-integer tag is also unneeded since the question is not about that, even if it mentions them.

Comment: there is no primitive type string and long or short apply to primitive types. what you think a string to be?

Comment: Post the code you currently have and explain why you think it's being defeated by the length of strings therein. It's very likely that it's not, since strings will be at least 2 GB max in all normal systems, and what could you possibly be doing that would need a longer one?

Comment: @underscore_d This is wrong. Many normal systems do not even have 2 MB RAM and way less than 2 GB.

Comment: Most implementations allow a `std::string` to be as long as you have RAM or about `SIZE_MAX` `char` long. Is your question about storing a sting across multiple segments of RAM? Segmentation is not common anymore except from some 8-bit micro controllers, but the 8086 CPU had it. In this case you would have to write your own class.

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 I guess "normal" was a bad choice of word; I meant "typical x86 desktop/laptop", which I might suppose is a more common newbie system than some embedded one, however common that embedded one might be.

Comment: I have made my question more readable now, could anyone clarify my doubt?

Answer (score 3):

> Do we have any data type that we can use to increase the length of the string?
>
> Like we have long long int, long double,

No, we don't. We don't even have a distinct built-in data type for strings in the first place. Strings are just arrays of `char`. And arrays can typically be as large as fits into memory, so there is no practical limit that would apply to lengths of strings that could be exceeded by another type.

Comment: If you use a x86 32 bit, your application is most likely limited to 2 GiB (Windows) or 3 GiB (Linux) even when your system has 12 GiB installed and the OS can access all of it, thanks to PAE. A 32bit x86 system is not that uncommon. Your statement would also be wrong for the 8086, but i think this system is not common anymore.

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 Depends on what you think "memory" means. In context of a C++ program, I see no reason to assume that it means anything other than memory available for the process.

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 considering Intel discontinued it 22 years ago after a 20 year run, I'd say its a safe bet "not common" would be an understatement.